# Android Blinking screen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My client has this requirement where he wants the phone to blink as old phones used to when getting a notification (remember the old Nokia 1100). Well, I have never seen an android phone do this so I'm not even sure that can be done.

I figured something similar could be accomplished by dimming and brighten up the screen light repeatedly. Here's my code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.screenBrightness = -1;
            getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

Problem is, since I'm on a broadcastReceiver I have no "getWindow()" method.

Anyways, do you think there's a simple way to do this?, maybe I'm not even approaching the right way.

Answer (score 0):

For your `BroadcastReceiver`, you are missing a vital point. A BroadcastReceiver is not meant to do very much processing at all - in fact the less it does, the better. Plus, you never know if the receiver app is in the background - asking a receiver for it's window does not make sense in the Android framework.

IMHO a BroadcastReceiver is there purely to receive an intent, and pass it directly onto an `Activity` or `Service` (and in rare cases to the `Application` object itself).

So in your case, you should be using the `BroadcastReceiver` to launch an `Activity`, that is perhaps a transparent activity. Inside there you could set up an animation that cycles the alpha values of a black background, and the transparent background. That might create your blinking.

The point is: don't do the processing in the `BroadcastReceiver`. If you follow this approach, you will find that the `Activity.getWindow()` method is what you need.

---

Regarding flashing the screen - if you want to be able to wake up the phone when it is asleep, and turn on the screen in that way, then you need to read up on wake locks. Unfortunately a full tutorial on how they work is really out of the scope of this question, but that should lead you in the right direction.

You might even enjoy Googling for CommonsWare's `WakefulIntentService`, however possibly not exactly what you need in this case.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Actually I used a much simpler approach since I figured that turning the screen on and off is an expensive task in terms of performance and battery life.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ran into this problem, here's how I "solved it".  I used a much simpler approach since I figured that turning the screen on and off is an expensive task in terms of performance and might even drain the battery. So, now I'm just calling another activity, turning on the screen and disabling the lock screen. This new activity has a handle that will toggle the layout background between the values black and white. That  simulates the blinking. Problem solved!.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helped you - using the `BroadcastReceiver` to launch an `Activity` which handles the blinking in some way seems like the best approach indeed.